# Geometric inequality with a triangle

Tags: geometry, analysis, inequality, contest-math, triangles

The positive real numbers $x,y,z$ are the side lengths of a triangle iff $$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 2\sqrt{x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2}$$

Comment: you have to replace $c$ with $z$.

Comment: How can this post (which isn't even a question) have two upvotes?

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a question...

Comment: Try put $x=a+b$,$y=b+c$,$z=c+a$.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question. Why do you say it isn't? The sides of a triangle need to satisfy the triangle inequality, and this inequality might be equivalent.

Comment: Try proving the other way around. Using heron's formula(As my friend did in his answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2\lt4(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2)\\
\Updownarrow\\
x^4+y^4+z^4-2x^2y^2-2y^2z^2-2z^2x^2\lt0\\
\Updownarrow\\
(x-y)^2(x+y)^2+z^4-2z^2\left(x^2+y^2\right)\lt0\\
\Updownarrow\\
\left(z^2-(x-y)^2\right)\left(z^2-(x+y)^2\right)\lt0\\
\Updownarrow\\
(z-x+y)(z+x-y)(x+y-z)(z+x+y)\gt0
$$
Which is true if and only if the [Triangle Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) is true for all sides.

If the quantity is not positive, at least one of the sides fails.

The perimeter factor, $x+y+z$, must be positive.

If two of the "triangle" factors is not positive, then one of the sides is not positive; e.g. if $(z-x+y)\le0$ and $(z+x-y)\le0$, then $2z=(z-x+y)+(z+x-y)\le0$. Thus, only one of the triangle factors can be negative.

So if the quantity is positive, all the factors must be positive.

---

[Heron's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) says that the area of a triangle is
$$
\frac14\sqrt{(z-x+y)(z+x-y)(x+y-z)(z+x+y)}
$$
which is
$$
\frac14\sqrt{4(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2)-(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}
$$